# Here maps - provided styles (omv) doesn't working

Tags: here-api

Trying using codes from [docs](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/styles/change-style-at-load) and pointing URLs to provided styles from npm repo ($ npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --save).

```
var style = new H.map.Style('{{ url('vendor/@here/omv/skeleton.yaml') }}', '{{ url('vendor/@here/omv/') }}/');
```

and only `normal.day.yaml` working as expected. Each other styles (japan.poi.day.yaml, poi.day.yaml, skeleton.yaml) doesn't working and against displaying map I get empty space.
In console I don't get errors.

Comment: The `normal.day.yaml` is the main style, while other files (e.g. `skeleton.yaml`) are imported from the main one (see `import: ...` statements).

So imports aren't supposed to be used as standalone styles, the map doesn't show anything because those files don't contain [minimal configuration](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/dev_guide/topics/structure-overview.html) or they rely on some `global.` consts defined in other files.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue:

```
             var here_apiKey = '....'
            var appId = 'xxx';
            var appCode = '......';
            var urlTpl =
            'https://{1-4}.{base}.maps.cit.api.here.com' +
            '/{type}/2.1/maptile/newest/{scheme}/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png' +
            '?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}' +
            '&apiKey={api_key}';
```

I can get  3 working :

```
            satellite.day

             hybrid.day

              terrain.day
```

But failed on following 3:

```
                pedestrian.day

                normal.day.transit

                normal.day
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of displaying Japan Map you need to be a platform user in HERE or contact to our sales team to get a valid credential.
Please see below documentation.
https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-japan.html